# Reg exp to match a specific HTTP response code in apache or nginx server logs

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regexp that could match a specific response code (error code) in apache or nginx webserver logs.

```
10.80.248.64 - - [02/Nov/2012:15:04:40 +0000] "GET //browse/OS HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "-"
10.220.64.11 - - [02/Nov/2012:15:04:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 491 "-" "Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)"
10.80.16.66 - - [29/Oct/2012:11:09:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"
```

The reg exp should be able to match lines with a specific error code like 404, 200 or 302.

Comment: `\].+(404|200|302)` is the simplest one I can think of, but this assumes the numbers don't show up in some other context in the string following the timestamp

Comment: But it's wrong. It has to match only HTTP log lines without matching other lines. I'm looking for a good solution.

Comment: `where is the language tag?`also using regex for this would not be good thing to do..there are good parsers available just for that purpose...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
^[^"]*"[^"]*\sHTTP\/[\d.]+"\s+(?:200|302|404)\s.*$
 └─┬─┘│└─┬─┘└┤└────┬─────┘│└┬┘└──────┬──────┘└┤└┤
   │  │  │   │     │      │ │        │        │ │
   │  │  │   │     │      │ │        │        │ └─ anything (including nothing)
   │  │  │   │     │      │ │        │        │ 
   │  │  │   │     │      │ │        │        └─ one space (white-space character)
   │  │  │   │     │      │ │        │
   │  │  │   │     │      │ │        └─ 200 or 302 or 404
   │  │  │   │     │      │ │
   │  │  │   │     │      │ └─ one or more spaces (white-space characters)
   │  │  │   │     │      │
   │  │  │   │     │      └─ one double-quote character
   │  │  │   │     │
   │  │  │   │     └─ HTTP/ followed by a combination of digit(s) and/or dot(s)
   │  │  │   │
   │  │  │   └─ one space (white-space character) 
   │  │  │
   │  │  └─ anything (including nothing) but double-quote character(s)
   │  │
   │  └─ one double-quote character
   │
   └─ anything (including nothing) but double-quote character(s)
```

Comment: In what context does this work? I can't make it work with grep, php or node. Some explanation could be helpful.

Comment: @AltimusPrime - Explanation of regex pattern meaning has been added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. What did you use to run this regex?

Comment: @AltimusPrime - There are many regex engines. I use PCRE engine. You can test this regex pattern at https://regex101.com/r/mgHqpP/1